# Is it possible and feasable to extend websharper to support decimal datatype?

Tags: f#, decimal, websharper

I am looking for a framework that will generate Javascript for the client side, and i am willing to learn more F# to do this.

It is mandatory to have a decimal fully compatible datatype in Javascript
Can it be done? 
Are there any guides for extending Websharper?

I noticed that on websharper website there is no link to forums and the websharper google group has latest post from 2011.

Is the project still active, maintained and developed?

Comment: Yes, it's very actively maintained. The main point of contact is at [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper). Paging @[toyvo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/386685/)...

Comment: As an alternative to WebSharper, you can also check out FunScript (https://github.com/ZachBray/FunScript). This is quite recent and actively developed F# to JavaScript translator with an open-source license that allows commercial use. It could be quite easily extended to support `decimal` _if_ there was a JS library implementing a fully compatible data type - finding or implementing such library is probably the key problem for both WebSharper and FunScript. For both, F# implementation would be sufficient (as it could be translated to JavaScript).